# How to check if button is pressed and working on LPT port in C++

Tags: c++, lpt

I have a button I got out of a random item around the house and I wanna hook it up to my LPT port and check if its pressed or not in C++ and if it is display a message.

Comment: What button? Can you post a more detailed question in what you are trying to do? Show us that you have done the research, googled around, tried it out...

Comment: Tom, this is HAcKLOrD you are talking to.

Comment: @Neil: am I supposed to know? forgive my ignorance, no disrespect there...

Comment: The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the inpout32.dll which will enable you to read/write from/to the LPT port. The usage of direct addressing of hardware ports is restricted, the dll will enable you to get around the restriction as it executes an internal driver which is already built into the dll and therefore communicating with the driver in an indirect fashion. The dll can be downloaded from [here](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html), there is one available for x64bit platform [here](http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/default.htm).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about accessing the parallel port, here is a good resource: [Lakeview Research](http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm)